# Gnome 3: how to enable desktop actions in dock entries?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

In Unity, it is possible to add desktop actions to dock items (*eg*, you can add a "New Private Window" action to *firefox.desktop* and it would appear as an option when you right-click the Firefox icon in the dock). I just installed Ubuntu Gnome, and though the desktop files appear to be the same as those in Unity, the desktop actions don't appear in the dock entries/icons. Is there any way to make this happen in Gnome?

Versions:
Ubuntu: 14.04 LTS
Gnome:  3.10.4

Example desktop action:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
...
Actions=NewPrivateWindow;

[Desktop Action NewPrivateWindow]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=firefox -private-window;
```

[Note that the line `OnlyShowIn=Unity;` has been removed.]

Desktop file location: */usr/share/applications/*

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten that I'd enabled Dash to Dock. That's the issue then. When DtD is enabled, the desktop actions don't appear in either the dash or the dock. Awesome.